# Proof about Cardinality/$\aleph_0$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

How can I prove that $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n < \aleph_0$$ I was recommended to use a diagonalization argument similar to that used to prove that $|\mathbb{R|} \neq \aleph_0$. Any idea what to do?

Comment: What is your definition of $\aleph_0?$  This probably comes from that.  It is certainly not a diagonalization argument.

Comment: Isn't aleph null about the size of a set?

Comment: I think he means $|\mathbb{N}|=\aleph_0$. And I also agree with @RossMillikan that this is not a diagonalization argument.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use the pigeonhole principle. Obviously $n\le \aleph_0$ for every $n$, so suppose $\aleph_0\le n$ for some $n$. Then $n+1\le\aleph_0\le n$, which is a contradiction to the pigeonhole principle. Do you see why?

Comment: I haven't learned about the Pigeonhole Principle yet, could you go a bit more in depth how it can be used to solve this problem?

Comment: You can't fit $n+1$ pigeons in $n$ holes - at least some pigeons have to double up. It's an informal way of stating that there is no injection from $n+1$ to $n$, which is exactly what $n+1\le n$ asserts by the definition of cardinal inequality. You can read more on wiki: [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)

Answer (score 0):

Construct subsets of increasing cardinality of the natural numbers that have cardinality $n$. By induction, they are always less than the aleph null.